# Calculating formula based on multiple columns in Pandas Dataframe - but without creating many intermediate columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have been trying to calculate the "True Range" formula based on a Pandas dataframe containing stock ticker prices history.

This is the formula:

```
TR = max [(high - low ), abs(high − close prev), abs ⁡(low − close prev)]
```

I have high, low and close as columns in the dataframe.

When I try to operate like this, I get invalid character identifier error which is not very helpful. I tried many changes and combninations in the following expression, but not successful.

```
df['TR']=((df['high']-df['low']), (df['high'] - df['adjclose'].shift(1)).abs(),(df['low'] - df['adjclose'].shift(1))).max(axis=1)
```

I know this can be achieved by three separate intermediate columns and taking a max of them. But, I want to avoid the same and do it directly.

Is there a way out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `concat` with `max`:

```
df['TR'] = pd.concat([(df['high'] - df['low']), 
                      (df['high'] - df['adjclose'].shift(1)).abs(),
                      (df['low']  - df['adjclose'].shift(1))], axis=1).max(axis=1)
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'high':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'low':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'adjclose':[1,3,5,7,1,0]})

print (df)
   adjclose  high  low
0         1     4    7
1         3     5    8
2         5     4    9
3         7     5    4
4         1     5    2
5         0     4    3

df['TR'] = pd.concat([(df['high']-df['low']), 
                      (df['high'] - df['adjclose'].shift(1)).abs(),
                      (df['low'] - df['adjclose'].shift(1))], axis=1).max(axis=1)

print (df)
  adjclose  high  low   TR
0         1     4    7 -3.0
1         3     5    8  7.0
2         5     4    9  6.0
3         7     5    4  1.0
4         1     5    2  3.0
5         0     4    3  3.0
```

**Detail**:

```
print (pd.concat([(df['high']-df['low']), 
                      (df['high'] - df['adjclose'].shift(1)).abs(),
                      (df['low'] - df['adjclose'].shift(1))], axis=1))
   0    1    2
0 -3  NaN  NaN
1 -3  4.0  7.0
2 -5  1.0  6.0
3  1  0.0 -1.0
4  3  2.0 -5.0
5  1  3.0  2.0
```

Numpy solution is different, because max of `NaN` in row is again `NaN`:

```
df['TR1'] = np.max(np.c_[(df['high']-df['low']), 
                        (df['high'] - df['adjclose'].shift(1)).abs(),
                        (df['low'] - df['adjclose'].shift(1))], axis=1)

print (df)
   adjclose  high  low  TR1
0         1     4    7  NaN
1         3     5    8  7.0
2         5     4    9  6.0
3         7     5    4  1.0
4         1     5    2  3.0
5         0     4    3  3.0

print (np.c_[(df['high']-df['low']), 
                        (df['high'] - df['adjclose'].shift(1)).abs(),
                        (df['low'] - df['adjclose'].shift(1))])

[[-3. nan nan]
 [-3.  4.  7.]
 [-5.  1.  6.]
 [ 1.  0. -1.]
 [ 3.  2. -5.]
 [ 1.  3.  2.]]
```

Comment: Makes sense  :) !

Comment: @RafaelC - I add numpy solution, there get `NaN`.

Comment: Thank you. Just for completion sake, missed the second abs() in the formula - that is my mistake (nothing to with the technical part of the question and the excellent technical answer), but to correct for record sake for people reading the Formula for True range (from a financial perspective: The right formula is missing one abs(). Adding it back.

df['TR'] = pd.concat([(df['high']-df['low']),(df['high'] - df['adjclose'].shift(1)).abs(),(df['low'] - df['adjclose'].shift(1)).abs()], axis=1).max(axis=1)

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by :

```
df['TR']=list(map(max,zip((df['high']-df['low']), (df['high'] - df['adjclose'].shift(1)).abs(),(df['low'] - df['adjclose'].shift(1)))))
```